# Route from computer A (DMZ) to computer B

Tags: iptables

I have a computer A on the DMZ and I would like to route everything that goes to port 5555 to computer B (192.168.1.10) on port 6666. I enabled net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1 in sysctl.conf and setup the following iptables rules:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 5555 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.10:6666
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

But that isn't working, any ideas on what I could be missing? Here's my iptables config.

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.9 on Sat Oct 23 19:25:17 2010                            
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [191:16773]
:TCP - [0:0]
:UDP - [0:0]
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.0/8 -i eth0 -j DROP 
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP 
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -j UDP 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m state --state NEW -j TCP 
-A INPUT -p udp -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 
-A INPUT -p tcp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset 
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-proto-unreachable 
-A TCP -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5555 -j ACCEPT 
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Oct 23 19:25:17 2010
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.9 on Sat Oct 23 19:25:17 2010
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [491:165229]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [17:2012]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [17:2012]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Oct 23 19:25:17 2010
```

Answer (score 1):

You have your FORWARD policy in the filter table set to DROP.